# CodeIgniter - Unable to add id parameter to redirect()

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I have the following controller code for editing a supplier form:

```
public function edit($supplier_id = NULL) {

    if ($this->session->userdata ( 'username' ) === NULL) {
        redirect ( 'login' );
    } else {

        // set validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules ( 'suppliers', 'Department', 'callback_combo_check' );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules ( 'nome', 'Employee No', 'trim|required' );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules ( 'morada', 'Employee Name', 'trim|required' );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules ( 'cp', 'Employee Name', 'trim|required' );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules ( 'localidade', 'Designation', 'trim|required' );

        if ($this->form_validation->run () == FALSE) {

            $data['supplier_data'] = $this -> Suppliers_model -> get_supplier($supplier_id);

            if (empty($data['supplier_data'])) {
                show_404();
            }

            $this->lang->load ( 'suppliers' );

            $data['suppliers'] = $this->Suppliers_model->get_suppliers();

            $data ['title'] = 'Dashboard';

            $this->load->view ( 'templates/head', $data );
            $this->load->view ( 'templates/menu' );
            $this->load->view ( 'suppliers/edit', $data );
            $this->load->view ( 'templates/scripts' );
            $this->load->view ( 'templates/footer' );

        } else {

            // pass validation
            $up_data = array (
                    'Tipo_Fornecedor' => $this->input->post ( 'suppliers' ),
                    'Nome_Fornecedor' => $this->input->post ( 'nome' ),
                    'Morada_Fornecedor' => $this->input->post ( 'morada' ),
                    'Codigo_Postal' => $this->input->post ( 'cp' ),
                    'Localidade' => $this->input->post ( 'localidade' )
            );

            // insert the form data into database  
            $this->db->where('Codigo_Fornecedor', $supplier_id);
            $this->db->update( 'tabela_fornecedores', $up_data );

            // display success message
            $this->session->set_flashdata ( 'msg', '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Supplier details updated to Database!!!</div>' );

            redirect ('suppliers/edit/'.$supplier_id);

        }       

    }
}
```

The result should be after updating the database, returning to the edit form with the OK message as is inside controller.
Problem is that when i redirect at the end to the url, in this case it redirects to itself, the redirect loses the $suppliers_id parameter so the controller hits the 404 error, beucase it cannot find a id for the supplier.

Example:
www.site.com/suppliers/edit/1

1 is the suppliers id, it loads the page correctly, i change whatever i need, submit the form, the values ARE updated, but when it hits the redirect part

```
redirect ('suppliers/edit/'.$supplier_id);
```

it goes to www.site.com/suppliers/edit/, since there is no id it hits the 404_show function on the start of the page.

What am i doing wrong, why does the redirect with $suppliers_id fail?

Best regards

Nuno Reis

Routing rule for the url

```
$route['suppliers/edit/(:any)'] = 'suppliers/edit/$1';
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the ***order*** of your re-route rules matters.  If you have a more specific rule *below* the one you're showing us, it would take precedence.

Comment: You are not checking `if ((int)$suppliers_id > 0) { /* some code */ }` before using it.

Comment: If your edit/id is segment 3 you could use `$this->uri->segment(3)` instead of $supplier_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thx for your input.

The issue was:

When opening the page to edit i got the id from the uri segment /$id (/3).
When posting the else {} part of the statment as enforced, so no $id on the link, gave the 404 error.

I just added a hidden field to the form that stores the /$id when edir form is loaded.
When posted, reaches the else {} gets the $id from the post and then uses it for the query and the redirect.

All is working fine now.

Once more thx for the replies.

Best regards

Nuno Reis